# C# change to different connection string to SQL Server when can't connect to first one

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I want to connect to a SQL Server database when I'm at home and outside. I can connect in both ways but I need to change connection string every time from public ip to local when I'm home. Is it possible to write a function that whenever it cannot connect via remote ip to use other hostname in connection string?
Please help I'm a beginner :)

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sure. You would put two connection strings in your config file. And when opening the connection to one fails, you try connecting with the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//.....
//.....
//..... YOUR CODE

     try
    {

        con = new SqlConnection(check_Active_Connection_String()); // Add this
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand r = new SqlCommand("SELECT Login FROM Users WHERE Login not like '%Wszyscy%'", con);

//.... YOUR CODE
//.... YOUR CODE
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I added my strings and added your code after 
public partial class Form1 : Form is that correct? Im receiving 
    {An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Comment: It must also be showing you error on line no. ? Check if that error is on my line of code or any other?

Comment: It would be appreciated if you edit your code and modify it with adding my code, so i could check?

Comment: before con.Open(); you have not initalized con object? please correct your code.

Comment: It Works! Thank you brother!

Answer (score 0):

This is my code after adding yours Dheeraj. Error is at  con.Open(); line

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    SqlConnection con;
    private string CS_1 = @"Data Source=99.88.88.156,33400\SQLMINFOR;Initial Catalog=Minfor;Integrated Security=False;Password=****;User ID=sa;";
    private string CS_2 = @"Data Source=BACKUP-MIN\SQLMIN;Initial Catalog=Minfor;Integrated Security=False;Password=****;User ID=sa;";

    public string check_Active_Connection_String()
    {
        string main_CS = "";
        if (try_CS(CS_1))
        {
            main_CS = CS_1;
        }
        else if (try_CS(CS_2))
        {
            main_CS = CS_2;
        }

        return main_CS;// use main_CS for your connection string further
    }

    private bool try_CS(string CS)
    {
        try
        {
            using (con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                con.Open();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox2.PasswordChar = '*';
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand r = new SqlCommand("SELECT Login FROM Users WHERE Login not like '%Wszyscy%'", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = r.ExecuteReader(); 

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["Login"]);
            }
            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();


        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.Exit();
        }


    }
```

Comment: write this before opening connection: con = new SqlConnection(check_Active_Connection_String());

Comment: check my answer, i have modified it.

Comment: What if your IP\Server changes?  You will have to change your code.  Better to put these connection string in your app config file to make it easier to change them later.